# Is there a problem more difficult than NP-complete in graph theory?

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, np-complete

There are some decision problems being NP-complete in graph theory, including the problem of deciding if a graph has a hamilton cycle, or determing the chromatic number. Since the number of labeled graphs is $2^\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$, I think that there are no problems in graph theory more
difficult than NP-complete.

- Is this conjecture true ?
- If not, are there even undecidable problems in graph theory ?

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in the answers to [this related mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11133/undecidable-graph-problems), which gives several undecidable graph-theoretic problems. (Of course, it's somewhat a matter of taste whether a given problem is really "graph-theoretic" or not.)

Answer (score 2):

Are you familiar with [#P-complete problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp-P)?  The prototypical example is:

> HC#: Given a graph $G$, how many Hamiltonian cycles does it have?

Clearly, an efficient solution to HC# would immediately solve the NP-complete Hamiltonian Cycle (HC) problem, and by extension all NP-complete problems.  On the other hand, it's not clear at all that an efficient solution to HC would be any help at all in solving HC#.

There are counting versions of almost any NP-complete problem you can think of: Given a graph $G$, how many 3-colorings does it have?  Given a graph $G$, and a positive integer $n$, how many vertex covers of size $n$ does $G$ have? Each is evidently at least as hard, and probably much harder, than the corresponding NP-complete decision problem.